# How to show that $\int_{0}^{r}\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi r^{2}}{4}$?

Tags: integration

The area of a circle with radius $r$ is $\pi r^{2}$, so in principle we should have $$\int_{0}^{r}\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi r^{2}}{4}.$$ But how do we prove this?

Comment: $x = r \sin \theta$

Comment: Hint: What is the area of the part of circle(centred at origin of radius $r$) in the first quadrant? How can this area be represented using Integration?

Comment: A proper answer to this question depends on a precise definition of $\pi$. The usual definition of $\pi$ as ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle is given by $$\pi=2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Using substitution $x=rt$ and integration by parts after that we can show that $$\int_{0}^{r}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx=\frac{r^2}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=r\sin t$ then
$$
\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx =r^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \cos^2t\ dt =r^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{\cos 2t+1}{2}\ dt =\frac{\pi r^2}{4}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $$x=r\cos(t)$$